# Why is this mime type incorrect?

Tags: mime-types

A HTML5 video I am implementing is not working in Internet Explorer 9. After some debugging, I found that the mime type of the mp4 file is as `application/octet-stream`. However, in my `.htaccess` file I have,

```
AddType video/ogg  .ogv
AddType video/mp4  .mp4
AddType video/webm .webm
```

What have I missed in defining mime types?

Comment: Does your server configuration allow parsing `.htaccess` files? Are your `.htaccess` files allowed to override the `AddType` MIME types?

Comment: How can I check to see if I'm allowed to override the AddType MIME? Yes my server allows parsing of .htaccess - I am using it a lot.

Comment: You'd be looking for [`AllowOverride FileInfo`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#allowoverride) or a more general `AllowOverride` configuration...

Comment: Thanks for that. I tried it in the htaccess and resulted in a 500 Internal Server Error.

Comment: Yeah, that has to be done in the main configuration -- if anyone could supply their own `.htaccess` that granted them access to overriding everything, there wouldn't be much point to it, right? :)

Comment: ..probably because that belongs in the httpd.conf? - oops.

Comment: I'm on a cpanel shared environment, and I have made some changes to my user accounts custom included conf file. "<Directory /home/user/public_html/>
AllowOverride All
</Directory>". I have then rewritten the httpd.conf with '/scripts/rebuildhttpdconf' and then restart httpd. This hasn't solved the problem. The mp4 I am trying to load is actually on a CDN  - not in my user directory - does this matter?

Comment: It appears when I loaded the mp4 file from my site it worked just fine - it was when loading it from the CDN that the MIME type was lost.

Comment: Don't forget to add that as an answer to the question and mark it accepted.

Comment: Hi I am having similar problem @willdanceforfun

did the answer below helped you ???

I am also loading videos from CDN and the MIME TYPE for mp4 is coming as application/octet-stream.... it is creating problem is IE 

If you found the answer pls share with me as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is:

The MIME types you add on your server cannot override the MIME type on the remote server. If the files hosted elsewhere are stored as a different MIME type, then it will not work. Make sure that the MIME type on the CDN is correct.

Answer (score -1):

- Does the mp4 video URI have a .mp4 extension?
- Does your VirtualHost/server configuration allow for .htaccess files (AllowOverride directive)?